# d3 js v5 and password protected directory in cpanel

Tags: ajax, apache, d3.js, promise, cpanel

Here's the problem I am facing:
I have a web application built using d3.js v5 and I am using cpanel as the hosting platform. The app loads a bunch of topojson and csv data files and plots them in the browser. Everything works fine as long as I don't protect the public_html directory with a password. The moment I do it, d3 does not read the data anymore and it throws the following errors.

For the json files:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: 401 Unauthorized at responseJson (d3.v5.js:5845)

And for the csv files:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: 401 Unauthorized at responseText (d3.v5.js:5806)

I have tried both with http and https connections to check if that would solve the issue but I still get the same errors. The only thing I can think of is that there is a conflict between the way d3 v5 loads the files (promises) and the privacy layer of cpanel but i couldn't find any solution out there.

Comment: I'm not a server specialist, but my guess is that this has nothing to do neither with D3 nor with cPanel directly: this is an AJAX/XHR/Promise issue regarding an Apache feature (password protection). Therefore, I believe you'll get help faster using tags like `promise`, `apache`, `AJAX` etc...

Comment: Thanks Gerardo! I edited it.